# php artisan schedule:run don't send emails

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I am trying to send emails from an scheduled laravel task, when I call the command from the application the email is sent, but when the command is called from the command line, it is executed but there is no email sent.
my command code is the next :

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendEmails extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'emails:send';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        try {
             Mail::send('emails.testmail', [ ], function ($m) { 
                $m->to('someona@gmail.com', 'Francisco Larios')->subject('Your Reminder!'); 
            });
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception("Error Processing Request", 1);

        }

    }
}
```

the code in the kernel file is the next:

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\Inspire::class,
        Commands\SendEmails::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    //{
    //    $schedule->command('inspire')->everyMinute();
    //}
}
```

the command I am running on the console is :

```
php artisan emails:send
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the smtp server I was using to send the emails, I just change it for another smtp server in my mail.php connfiguration file an so, It works for both application and command line execution.